# IIS URL REWRITE 404 FOR FILE TYPE

Tags: iis

I have a directory of avatar images that some avatars have been deleted to clear space. What is an IIS URL Rewrite that can redirect images not found in a directory or by file extension of .jpg to default.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the URL Rewrite module being helpful here, but you can try the following:

In the directory with all your images create a new `web.config` file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
   <system.webServer>
          <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
             <error statusCode="404" path="https://my.coolsite.com/images/404avatar.png" responseMode="Redirect" />
         </httpErrors>
   </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

You are telling IIS to redirect to an existing image in case an image in this directory is not found.

I don't like the idea that we have to use an absolute URL here, but the other options for error pages (Insert Content and Execute URL) did not work for me.

You can do the same in the UI, select the directory and choose `Error Pages` then edit the 404 entry to `Respond with a 302 redirect`